# How do you share a PowerPoint presentation and have it open to a specific slide?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, onedrive, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I'm sharing a PowerPoint presentation on OneDrive.

Is there a way to specify that, when it's opened, it opens at a specific slide?

Answer (score 0):

From a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229/how-do-i-hyperlink-to-a-specific-slide-of-a-ppt-file):

Link to http://www.whatever.com/hello.ppt#4 for slide 4 to be opened initially.

However, I have not tested this with OneDrive yet.

Comment: If it works, it's not with OneDrive.  :(